# Як вимовляти "ч"?

Tags: фонетика

Я зростав у суржикомовному середовищі, тому про те, що "ч" в українській мові має вимовлятися твердо, дізнався лише в університеті, коли мені прямим текстом зауважили, що я "чьокаю".

Але питання в тому, **наскільки** вона мусить бути твердою? Куди бігти тренуватися таким, як я?

Скажімо, Олександр Авраменко [вимовляє "ч"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=64IlCANYAd4) ідеально чи переграє?

Сумніви мене взяли, коли я відкрив статті на wiktionary й там у вимові мені почало ввижатися м'яке "ч" (до прикладу, [*четвер*](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5d/Uk-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80.ogg), [*вдача*](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/64/Uk-%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0.ogg))

Comment: Не маю достатньо знань, щоб докладно відповісти на питання, але чисто суб'єктивно — мені ріже вухо "четвер" та "вдача" по посиланнях. 

Я виріс у Києві у двомовному середовищі (вдома батько говорив українською, мама російською, дитячий садок та школа - україномовні, але більшість друзів російськомовні), якщо це важливо, і я вимовляю "ч" значно твердіше українською.

Comment: Ще: [четвер](http://shtooka.net/listen/ukr/четвер), [четвер](https://uk.forvo.com/search/четвер/), [вдача](http://shtooka.net/listen/ukr/вдача), [вдача](https://uk.forvo.com/search/вдача/) — на мою суб'єктивну думку, лише частина вимовляє «правильно» (твердо як я).

Comment: Це суб'єктивно (тому коментар, а не відповідь), але ось, на мою думку, чудова вимова: [«Прокинувся хазяїн вранці»](https://youtu.be/jrnVrb0L8MU) (YouTube; увага, присутня *лексика* :)). Там не лише `/ч/` та `/ў/`, а й правильні голосні, особливо наголошена `/и/`.

Comment: Авраменко говорить правильно. Wikionary використовує записи з The Shtooka Project, де просто жахлива вимова українських слів.

Comment: За моїми спостереженнями черкашщани мають свій особливий звук ч :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Дуже рекомендую ознайомитися з Погрібний М. І. Українська літературна вимова (1992) "[16 - Шиплячi звуки](https://youtu.be/dUrx793sn2I?t=1h24m44s)" (решта теж буде корисною; також доступне [тут](//toloka.to/t32107)).

Це автор орфоепічного словника, і єдина мені відома повна праця щодо української вимови.

Щодо ваших прикладів:

1) Авраменко не переграє ані краплі. Це правильна вимова.
2) Як уже зазначали в коментарях, вимова з наведених прикладів wiktionary жахлива.

Довести це об'єктивно, сказати чітко "наскільки" доволі складно.

Тепер поради зі свого досвіду переходу на українську вимову (докази навести складно):

1) Перегравати ДУЖЕ складно. Вимовляйте "ч" ЯКОМОГА твердіше. У вас все одно навряд вийде вимовити надто твердо. А навіть якщо вийде, це швидко минеться.

2) Кінчик язика має бути вертикальним, має бути високо (не в горизонтальній частині біля зубів, а позаду).

3) Не забувайте, що навіть перед "і" звук "ч" лише напівпом'якшений. Тобто язик десь посередині між звичною вам російською вимовою і описаною вище твердою українською вимовою.

4) Про всяк випадок: щ = шч, це два окремих звуки, і вимова "ч" у "щ" нічим не відрізняється від "ч" окремо, тобто тверда. І напівпом'якшена перед "і".

Answer (score 1):

Тверде Ч це якщо ми говоримо про літературний стандарт.
М'яке Ч не має стосунку до суржику. В давньослов'янській Ч було м'яке.
тому в ряді діялектів так і зосталося.
Проте літературний стандарт і розмовна мова різні речі. літератуний стандарт це лише підмножина української мови.

В ряді діялектів (галицько-буковинська група говорів, степовий говір, слобожанський говір) ч собі м'яке.

Тому говоріть так, як вам подобається. Чи тверде ч має вас хвилювати якщо ви хочете працювати на радіо, телебаченні чи побідних сферах.